# How to remove duplicates in a file using Azure Data Factory without using Dataflow or Databricks or Azure datalake analytics

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am creating a data pipeline to copy data from one file to another. My input file has 4 columns and my output file has 2 columns. I want to copy only column 1 and column 3 of input file and store it in output file. Once that is copied I want to remove the duplicates from the output file. But I cannot use Dataflow or Databricks or Azure datalake analytics because I don't have compute in my setup.
Is there any way to do it without using compute ?

Answer (score 3):

You need a compute environment for de-duping. There are pre-built patterns in the ADF pipeline gallery for distinct rows and de-dupe.

Comment: ya once I have compute env, it can be easily done. But unfortunately we don't have compute on our env yet. So I was exploring something without compute.

Comment: Not sure how you would compute duplicates without a compute env

Answer (score 1):

We have two ask ,

1. Copy selected columns : We can do that and select the columns two be copied  under "mapping" . Its possible .

2.Removing duplicates : I think its a transformation and at this time , its not possible .

If you want to use Azure data lake analytics ( ADLA ) , I think you can achieve that by USQL .

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-data-lake-analytics

Comment: Let us just be clear: You CAN do this, but you need a compute engine. Data Flows, Databricks, SQL, ADLA ... doesn't matter. But those are all compute environments. And they can all help with de-duping.